# Javascript Show for a php login form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a login form, when you log in then the Login in button disappears and gets replaced with a My account button.

So far i have made it that when you login the login hides however i need to show a different div when logged in.

This is so far what i have :

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#pre_header_content_right').remove();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <script>


    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I am looking for a piece of code similar to this however instead or removes a div it shows it.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
                $('#pre_header_content_right').remove();
            });
```

I have dried .show instead of .remove however this does not work 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not simply show what you need as HTML instead of using jquery? `<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>
    <div>Login form here</div>
    <?php
} else {
    ?><div>other div here</div>
    <?php
}
?>`

Comment: I agree with mplungjan, you are doing the login check in PHP anyway, just display the intended div directly. You should always expect visitors that have JavaScript disabled and make the site usable without it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<script>
<?php 

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#button_login').show();
            $('#button_my_account').hide();
        });

    <?php
} else {
    ?>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button_login').hide();
     $('#button_my_account').show();
});



    <?php
}
?>   
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, This works, however the problem is that the button i want to remove when you are logged in is in the navigation. Now this navigation is included on every page

Comment: And what's the problem ? You can include the two button on each navigation and set the property display of the button "my account" to hide by default.